# What does the less than sign (<) for class mean?

Tags: ruby

Following code is from Ruby on Rails.

```
  ...some code here...

  unless ActionController::Base < ActionController::Testing
    ActionController::Base.class_eval do
      include ActionController::Testing
    end
  end

  ... some code here...
```

What does `ActionController::Base < ActionController::Testing` mean in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a test for inheritance and returns a boolean.

If the following statement is true, that means the left side is a subclass of the right side.

```
ActionController::Base < ActionController::Testing
```

See the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html#method-i-3C) for details.

Comment: Really quick and pricise answer. Thanks @merlin2011.